# Azure - never ending Full Backup Uploading in Database Migration Service

Tags: azure, dms, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have been migrating some databases from a SQL Server to an SQL Managed Instance. 13 of 14 DBs have been successfully restored. There is only one remaining, the biggest one with almost 600 Gb. It has been more than a week continuously uploading the initial full backup and it is still running.

It is a big database but I thought it has been a long time and it should have been finished by now. For this reason I have been trying some cmd/az commands but I don´t get anything more than a running status.
The strange thing is that I can´t see the DB (in recovery mode) in the SQL Management Studio and the file has not been created yet in the container of the Storage Account. All the other databases appear in SSMS and in the storage account.

I had around 75 Gb more than the total size of the databases in the Storage Account, so I guess that was not the issue. In any case, I added 500 Gb more but still no results.

Is it possible to stop the task and restart it to see if this helps? Obviously I would not like to upload all databases again if possible.

Could you please help ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to open a case with Support to make sure there is no patching or failover happening on the SQL MI during Migration.

I have seen this happen before where the restore is going through for a VLDB and then patching on SQL MI causes it to restart restoring again.

Hopefully this will help

Comment: Thank you, yes, I opened a case. It is taking ages and I don´t see any progress or errors.

Comment: Thanks for asking. It took me a while in any case. Just finished 3 days ago.Finally, yes, I had contact MS and they helped me but we needed some tries. First MS checked the background and the server was having some performance and network issues. We tried again, and after 2 and half weeks uploading, all the DBs were uploaded but the last one failed. NOTE: Use at least the double storage space than your full backups size, at least during the upload. 3 try was the good one. We separated the big databases into different activities and it went to 2-3 days uploading. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: cool.. thanks for the information and glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the comments before, the best options for the migration of old SQL Servers in my case were:

- Check regularly the cpu and network performance of the server.
- When you configure your SQL MI, use at least the double storage size of the full DB backups size.
- Finally, if you have big DBs, (my case more than 400Gbs), create different activities* to separate the small ones from the big ones. This would help as well if any errors happen into the big DBs. You won´t need to upload all of them again.
  *NOTE. I had some issues when I had more than 2 activities: Some of them stayed in "Queued" Status and after a day still did not run. This happened even when the other activities were already completed. So, to fix this, I had to delete all the activities and create the remaining one again.

Have a good day.